# Access all nodes in neo4j

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, neo4j

On rails console i am trying to call

`@invoice = Invoice.all`

which returns me some object like

`<Neo4j::Traversal::Traverser:0x817382>`

but when i tried to loop over the object like

`@invoice.each { |t| p t.number }`

i got nil,but database contains data for invoice.

**Invoice class**

`class Invoice < Searchable`

`include Neo4jrb::Paperclip`

`include LinkableEntity`

`include HeadsupNotify`

`enable_optimistic_locking`

`before_destroy :verify_links, :prepend => true`

`before_destroy :destroy_invoice_items`

`property :number, :type => :string`

`property :currency, :default => Money.default_currency.to_s`

`property :date, :pay_by_date, :type => :date`

`property :purchase_order_number`

`property :settle, :default => false`

`property :link_1, :link_2, :type => :string`

`index :number, :type => :fulltext`

`domain_property :details`

`money_property :total_cost, :receivable_amount`

`attr_protected :total_cost, :receivable_amount`

`attr_accessor :delink_receipt`

`validates :total_cost, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0}`

`validates :receivable_amount, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0}`

`validates :date,:number, :customer_id, :event_id, :project_id, :department_id,
            :brand_id, :premise_id, :user_id, :currency, :presence => true`

`validates :link_1, :length => { :maximum => 250 }`

`validates :link_2, :length => { :maximum => 250 }`

`validate :number_uniqueness`

`validate :invoice_items_present`

`validate :invoice_items_currency`

`validate :issue_credit_notes_valid`

`validate :pay_by_date_valid, :unless => "date.nil?"`

`validate :check_not_linked, :on => :update`

`has_one(:event).from(Event, :invoices_for_event)`

`has_one(:project).from(Project, :invoices_for_project)`

`has_one(:department).from(Department, :invoices_for_department)`

`has_one(:brand).from(Brand, :invoices_for_brand)`

`has_one(:premise).from(Premise, :invoices_for_premise)`

`has_one(:user).to(User)`

`has_one(:customer).from(Customer, :invoices_for_customer)`

`alias :party :customer`

`has_n(:invoice_items).to(InvoiceItem)`

`has_n(:receipts).from(Receipt, :paid_invoices)`

`has_n(:issue_credit_notes).from(IssueCreditNote, :credit_notes_for_invoice)`

`has_one(:invoices_for_settle).to(Settle)`

`links :receipts, :issue_credit_notes,:invoices_for_settle`

`has_neo4jrb_attached_file :photo`

`{:customer => :name, :event => :name, :department => :name, :project => :name, :brand =>      :name,
    :premise => :name, :user => :email}.each do |target, method|
    delegate method, :to => target, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true
  end`

`accepts_id_for :customer, :event, :project, :department, :brand, :premise, :user`

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_items, :allow_destroy => true`

`validates_associated :invoice_items`

`validates :customer_name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 100 }`

`validates :event_name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 100 }`

`validates :premise_name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 100 }`

`validates :project_name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 100 }`

`validates :brand_name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 100 }`

`validates :department_name, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 100 }`

`validates :link_1, :length => { :maximum => 250 }`

`validates :link_2, :length => { :maximum => 250 }`

`after_validation :set_total_cost`

`serialize :methods => :invoice_items`

`before_validation :delink`

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you been able to get a Cypher or Gremlin query working in Neo4j Console to see if you have the correct logic? This always helps me when I'm trying to use a secondary API with Neo4j.

Comment: @CameronTinker Ya Cypher query is working fine...

Comment: What does the Invoice class look like ? It should work:  Example: ```class Foo < Neo4j::Rails::Model; end; Foo.create!; Foo.all.each{|i| puts i.props.inspect}```

Comment: Hi @AndreasRonge this did not work and i have added the invoice class code in the question.

Comment: Hard to say with such a big class. Can you try to get it still not working with much less code ?

Comment: @AndreasRonge i cannot do any thing with the size of my class because like this i have other classes also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of how to do this with Ruby On Rails, but if your Invoice objects (nodes) are in a lucene full text index, you could use a Cypher query to return all Invoices.

Something like:
`START invoices=node:Invoices('name: *') RETURN invoices;`